# copy_to_user not working in linked list linux kernel module

Tags: linux, list, module, kernel

I'm having an issue with copy_to_user macro when writing a linux kernel module. With this code:

```
int err;
struct myElement *el;
list_for_each(cursor,&headList){
  el=list_entry(cursor,struct myElement,link);
  printk("data ptr= %s, data len=%d\n",el->data,el->i);
  err=copy_to_user(buforUz,el->data,el->i);
  printk("err=%d\n",err);
        }
```

When Im using cut I can check with dmesg that printk shows correct values (previously saved string in allocated memoery, pointer to the memory where the string is stored and the string lenght), but copy_to_user copies nothing. When Im using strace it shows that it copied 0 bytes:

```
read(3, "", 65536)                      = 0
```

What can possibly be the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue. My problem was that I didn't return the lenght I've read, but 0 which is wrong, and that's why it didn't show anything.